# How to pipe rawvideo to v4l2loopback using ffmpeg?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, v4l2

I am trying to process a video by OpenCV in Python and then send each frame to a virtual camera (i.e., v4l2loopback). I have seen questions asked where OpenCV output is piped to ffmpeg and saved into a file, and other questions where a video file is piped to v4l2 using ffmpeg, but no question where these two are combined. I can do either of the above two things on their own, but not combined.

My Python code uses a subprocess to pipe each frame to ffmpeg. The ffmpeg command for piping the output of OpenCV to an .mp4 file is

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt bgr24 -i - -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset fast output.mp4
```

This works and I have tested it.

The ffmpeg command to pipe a video file to the v4l2 virtual camera is

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

This also works and I have tested it.

I tried combining the above two commands and came up with

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt bgr24 -i - -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset fast -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

but I get the following error

> [NULL @ 0x55a12fcc60] Unable to find a suitable output format for ''
>   : Invalid argument

I would be glad if anyone could help me figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. The `Unable to find a suitable output format` error is probably from a quotation/escaping issue within the command in your code. Running the same command from a command-line interface executes properly.
2. Once you fix the quoting issue you will get another error: `V4L2 output device supports only a single raw video stream`. This means you can't use libx264 to output to v4l2. So instead let it automatically choose rawvideo output:

```
    ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format bgr24 -i - -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

If the colors look wrong, either use a different `-pixel_format` value (see `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`), or the player does not support the output pixel format being used by v4l2. In that case add `-vf format=yuv420p` output option (anywhere after `-i` and before `/dev/video0`).

More info:

- [rawvideo demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) (also `ffmpeg -h demuxer=rawvideo`)
- [V4L2 output device](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#v4l2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why do you still have output.mp4 in the command? I only want to output to the v4l2 device.

Comment: @sepehr78 I assumed you wanted to output to both v4l2 and mp4 because you said, " can do either of the above two things on their own, but not combined.". I'll update the answer without mp4.

Comment: I tried the command and the code is running and it seems that the video is being piped to v4l2, but what I look at the output of the v4l2 device, the colors are very distorted. Why do you think this might be?

Comment: @sepehr78 Probably wrong `-pixel_format`. See `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` for a list.